# Notice: WP_Block_Type_Registry::register was called incorrectly. Block type names must contain a namespace prefix

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a Gutenburg ACF block, following [this tutorial](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/).

And I get the error below:

```
Notice: WP_Block_Type_Registry::register was called incorrectly. Block type names must contain a namespace prefix.
```

I found [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/new-block-json-method-yields-no-block-types-exist/#post-157203) on the ACF forum and tried all the solutions with no luck.

My current code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( get_template_directory_uri(). '/blocks/testimonial' );
}
```

I also tried this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( get_template_directory_uri(). '/blocks/testimonial/block.json' );
```

And this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/blocks/testimonial' );
}
```

And also this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/blocks/testimonial/block.json' );
}
```

I verified all my file paths.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error as you, and was working exactly on the same example as well. What I did notice is that the error kept showing not because the "name" in JSON file was lacking the prefix, but because it was treating the file path to json file as a name (in register_block_type() function usually the first parameter was the name) - when I changed the function to this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_blocks' );
function register_blocks() {
    register_block_type( dirname(__FILE__) . '/blocks/testimonial/block.json' );
}
```

the error changed to one about the name shouldn't contain uppercase letters.

So, in my case, the deal was with the wrong file paths after all - I was trying to run this function from another folder (had my functions.php just collecting other php files and was trying to run it using get_template_directory_uri() as the path helper at first too ). In the end, I put the above snippet in my base functions.php file and it started to work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the [block name](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/glossary/#block-name) in your `block.json` is missing the *namespace* prefix, eg: add "project-name/" with your unique plugin/project name:

**block.json**

```json
{
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "project-name/testimonial",
...
}
```

After you have updated `name` with a unique prefix, use a unique function name to register your block in PHP:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'register_project_name_testimonial_block' );

function register_project_name_testimonial_block() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/blocks/testimonial' );
}
```

The [register_block_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/) function looks for `block.json`, so no need to specify it. The [ACF documention uses `register_acf_blocks`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/) as the function name, but if you have more than one block in your project, then you are overwriting the same function. The duplicate function names may be another reason if your block isn't loading if the namespace and path to `block.json` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The path passed to `register_block_type` needs to be a valid server path, not a web address, to the directory containing your block.json file, so the examples with `get_template_directory_uri` will definitely not work.

The best way to debug this problem is to echo the value you are passing to the function and then verify it exists on the server.  For example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    $myblock =  __DIR__ . '/blocks/testimonial';
    var_dump($myblock);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens for me when I'm registering a block this way:

```
function create_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
```

but I forgot to actually build the project

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

get_template_directory_uri() is returning a trailing '/'. The function  register_block_type cannot cope with two slashes inside the path string.

Change to this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( get_template_directory_uri(). 'blocks/testimonial' );
}
```

and it should work fine.